# how to run a python script after detect the insertion of usb drive

Tags: python, cron, removable-storage

I have 2 python scripts

1. the first detect the last insert USB drive.
2. the second is to perform a backup of the folders and files from a
   USB drive .

## detectusb.py

```
import win32api
import win32file

# Returns a list containing letters from removable drives
drive_list = win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings()
drive_list = drive_list.split("\x00")[0:-1]  # the last element is ""

for letter in drive_list:
    if win32file.GetDriveType(letter) == win32file.DRIVE_REMOVABLE:# check if the drive is of type removable 

print("list drives: {0}".format(letter))
```

What i want is to combine these t scripts and run the first script once the user insert the USB  i don't know if the **cron** will do the job  but i need to run the script like **autorun**.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run Python script on USB flash-drive insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44897023/how-to-run-python-script-on-usb-flash-drive-insertion)

Comment: i am using the script on windows machine so i don't think this work for me